# Redirection execution order?

Tags: command-line, redirect

I wonder why the standard errors are always output first despite the redirection order in my commands:

"first `>` then `2>&1`"

```
lyg@lyg-VirtualBox:~$ > txt
lyg@lyg-VirtualBox:~$ ls txt  tt ttt > txt  2>&1
lyg@lyg-VirtualBox:~$ cat txt
ls: cannot access tt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ttt: No such file or directory
txt
```

"first `2>` then `1>&2`"

```
lyg@lyg-VirtualBox:~$ ls txt  tt ttt 2> txt  1>&2
lyg@lyg-VirtualBox:~$ cat txt
ls: cannot access tt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ttt: No such file or directory
txt
```

What is the detailed procedure of redirection for each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ls` stats all the files first, outputs error messages for the missing files, then it sorts the existing filenames and outputs them.

So the redirections have no impact on the order of the output. You can test this by writing a simple command that outputs something to both fds, and their order will be the same

```
$ f() { echo stdout; echo stderr >&2; }
$ f > /tmp/output 2>&1
$ cat /tmp/output
stdout
stderr
$ f 2> /tmp/output >&2
$ cat /tmp/output
stdout
stderr
```